# spring oauth2 token caching

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using spring oauth2 for generating bearer tokens and validating them. I store tokens in database. I would like to know that is there any facility provided by spring oauth2 to cache the token as it is costly to go to db and fetch the token for validation when the servers are hit by 100tps.

Comment: did you solved somehow caching?

Answer (score 0):

I get that this is old but for the benefit of others.

Try not to store tokens anywhere unless you need the facility to revoke them.  If you are committed to not storing them, that by default means you are (or should) be using JWT formatted tokens.

Spring, by default, includes user data in the bearer access JWT token that is produced.

Therefore your client / resource server that is a recipient of the JWT token has enough knowledge to automatically create an authentication object and manage access to resources.